# sending file to server and receiving it back on client side tcp java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming

1.client is sending file succesfully to server

2.server receives file successfully

But
3. when server tries to send this file back to client ,after working on received file( sent by client) following error occurs :

socket:null

connection is closed

This is sending file method back to client

### "server code: "

```
public void sendFileBack(String fileName)
throws UnknownHostException,FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.0.103", 13267);
  String tmpName=fName.replace(".mcrl2", ".lps");
  File myFile = new File("out" + "\\" +tmpName );
  byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
  //bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);  

  DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
  dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
  OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();

  //Sending file name and file size to the server  
  DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
  dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
  dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
  dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
  dos.flush();

  //Sending file data to the server  
  os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
  os.flush();
  console.append("\n\n Output file transfered successfully \n \n");


  //Closing socket  
  sock.close();
}
```

This is receiving file method back from server

### "client code:"

```
private void receiveFileBack() throws IOException {

  int bytesRead;
  int port; 

  ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
  while (true) {
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.print("accepted connection"+clientSocket);

    InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);

    String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
    System.out.print(fileName+"..........");

    File f =new File("serverOut\\"+fileName);
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("serverOut\\"+fileName);

    long size = clientData.readLong();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    while (size > 0 && 
           (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
      serverStatus.append("Reading file..\n");
      output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

      size -= bytesRead;
    }

    // Closing the FileOutputStream handle  
    output.close();
    output.flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace for us?

Comment: @Fildor :  java.lang.NullPointerException
  connectionSocket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=53150,localport=4444]
  SEVERE: null
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:203)

Comment: java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:203)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:337)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
 at mcrl2.MainFrame.receiveFileBack(MainFrame.java:1353)
 at mcrl2.MainFrame.access$4200(MainFrame.java:48)
 at mcrl2.MainFrame$41.run(MainFrame.java:1402)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 40 seconds)

Comment: Can you mark line 1353 in your Code? Nah, forget it ... You are flushing _after_ closing `output`!

Comment: @Fildor : ive corrected that "flushing after closing output "

Comment: this is the piece of code at line 1353 :   InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);
            String fileName = clientData.readUTF();

Comment: icantunderstandthecodebecauseofthelackofformatting